# how to get arithmetic operations without period

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this piece of code to get operators using regex:

```
    string[] num = Regex.Split(calcu.Text, @"\-|\+|\*|\/").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
        string[] op = Regex.Split(calcu.Text, @"\d{1,3}").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
        double numCtr = 0, lastVal = 0;
        string lastOp = "";
        foreach (string n in num)
        {
            numCtr++;
            if (numCtr == 1)
            {
                lastVal = double.Parse(n);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastOp))
                {
                    switch (lastOp)
                    {
                        case "+":
                            lastVal = lastVal + double.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            lastVal = lastVal - double.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "*":
                            lastVal = lastVal * double.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "/":
                            lastVal = lastVal / double.Parse(n);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            double opCtr = 0;
            foreach (string o in op)
            {
                opCtr++;
                if (opCtr == numCtr)
                {
                    lastOp = o;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        calcu.Text = lastVal.ToString();
```

If add 20.5+2.5 the period in the number is selected and the returned answer is 20.5, but if I use 20+5.5 it will result to 25.5.

If I use 20+7.5+20+5.5 the result is correct.

I just don't know how to unselect the period so i can do operations whenever position i do.

Comment: Are you not worried of **Operator precedence** rules for output?

Answer (score -1):

i used this code and substitute it to the array

```
    string value = calcu.Text;
        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters);
        string[] signs = Regex.Split(value, "[0-9]|\\.").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray(); ;
        float numCtr = 0, lastVal = 0;
        string lastOp = "";
        foreach (string n in parts)
        {
            numCtr++;
            if (numCtr == 1)
            {
                lastVal = float.Parse(n);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastOp))
                {
                    switch (lastOp)
                    {

                        case "+":
                            lastVal = lastVal + float.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            lastVal = lastVal - float.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "*":
                            lastVal = lastVal * float.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "/":
                            lastVal = lastVal / float.Parse(n);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            float opCtr = 0;
            foreach (string o in signs)
            {
                opCtr++;
                if (opCtr == numCtr)
                {
                    lastOp = o;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        calcu.Text = lastVal.ToString();
```

and it worked,